# laravel many to many with third table

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, many-to-many, pivot

I'm using Laravel and trying to grab info from a foreign relationship of a member of a pivot. ERD is below. I have set up a many to many relationship so that I can grab property restrictions with $property->restriction and the other way around. What I'm struggling with is how I can add in the restriction type description when I grab this info.

**$property->restriction** gives me the type_id

```
 array(
     'id' => '1',
     'description' => 'Fish only',
     'restriction_types_id' => '1',
     'pivot' => array(
       'property_id' => '17',
       'restriction_id' => '1'
     )
   )
```

but I want something like this with the **restriction_type description** instead of its id.

```
 array(
     'id' => '1',
     'description' => 'Fish only',
     'restriction_type' => 'Animals',
     'pivot' => array(
       'property_id' => '17',
       'restriction_id' => '1'
     )
   )
```

My DB tables

```
╔═════════════╗      ╔════════════════════╗      ╔════════════════════╗
║  property   ║      ║property_restriction║      ║restriction         ║
╟─────────────╢      ╟────────────────────╢      ╟────────────────────╢
║id           ║——————║property_id         ║   ┌──║restriction_id      ║
║description  ║      ║restriction_id      ║───┘  ║desctiption         ║
╚═════════════╝      ╚════════════════════╝   ┌──║restriction_type_id ║
                                              │  ╚════════════════════╝
                                              │
                                              │
                     ╔═══════════════════╗    │
                     ║restriction_type   ║    │
                     ╟───────────────────╢    │
                     ║id                 ║────┘
                     ║description        ║
                     ╚═══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way you are currently trying to access the data is through a dynamic property. It may be possible to just type out `$property->restriction->restriction_type`. 
You can also try to eager load it in one of the ways below:

```
$property->with('restriction','restriction.restriction_type')->get();
```

or

```
$property
    ->with('restriction')
    ->with('restriction.restriction_type')
    ->get();
```

If neither of these ways work I would research eager loading and the dynamic properties of Laravel and see if there is something that needs to get altered in your relationships.